# NuGet Package Manager to manage packages fills hard drive over time

Tags: nuget, diskspace

I have an application that uses NuGet packages to manage versions of tooling available to an instance of the application.

For instance, A Test Manager, the actual Tests that are executed by the Manager are contained in a .nupkg file. If you want to change which tests are executed all you have to do is replace the .nupkg file. When the application runs it finds the package and uses the package manager to get all the files out and add them into my app domain.

The package manager extracts all the files into a temp folder and returns the directory they were extracted to.

Unfortunately every time the application runs it extracts to a new random location because of this block of code in OptimizedZipPackage:
`protected virtual string GetExpandedFolderPath()
{
     return Path.GetRandomFileName();
}`

Yes it is virtual and I can override it in my own version of the package, but in order to use my own version of the package I also have to have my own version of the LocalPackageRepository class, with an override.

What I'm hoping for is an way to get fixed folder names so it uses the same folder for the same package/version every time without having to write override classes.

Comment: If you need the fixed folder names then the only way to do that is what you suggested - use your own version of LocalPackageRepository. If you are only concerned with the used disk space then you could call the OptimizedZipPackage.PurgeCache(). Visual Studio and NuGet.exe call this when they shutdown.

Comment: Why do they let this directory fill up indefinitely?  Is there some recommended best practice for managing this?  These folders are getting rather large on our workstations and TFS build agents.  I could setup a scheduled task or call PurgeCache manually, but that seems a bit hokey to need to do that.

Comment: I tried running OptimizedZipPackage.PurgeCache(); directly and it didn't do anything.  Does it need some sort of special setup or is it not something you can call manually?  Whatever the case, it's definitely not purging anything on my machine or our TFS build agents.